# Gaussian-like integration by parts on the high-dimensional hypersphere

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Denote $\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})$ the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $\sqrt{n}$. Recall Stein's lemma (Gaussian integration by parts), which reads for every function $f_n$ such that the expectations below are well-defined:
$$\mathbb{E}_{Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Id)}[Z_1 f_n(Z)] = \mathbb{E}_{Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Id)}[\partial_1 f_n(Z)].$$

My goal is to prove that this relation holds also asymptotically for large $n$ when the measure is no longer Gaussian but is uniform over $\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})$. This is natural since we expect the Gaussian measure to concentrate on $\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})$. So I would like to have a bound for 
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})}[Z_1 f_n(Z) - \partial_1f_n(Z)] \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}Z)\right|$$ when $\mu_n$ is the uniform measure over $\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})$. This bound should depend on the function $f_n$ (via Lipschitz constants for example) and on $n$. Does there exists such bounds ?

Comment: What is the domain of the function $f$? It seems that it is $\mathbb R^n$, but $n$ is changing, isn't it?

Comment: True, I should write $f_n$ instead of $f$.

Comment: Ok, but then what do you ask about the sequence $(f_n){n\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: I have a priori no requirements about $f_n$ (except that all these quantities are well-defined). But if regularity or Lipschitz properties allow to derive a bound, I would be interested as well.

Comment: My point is, you have to ask that in some appropriate sense the functions $(f_n)$ are "compatible". Otherwise if for any $n$ I can choose any function $f_n$ I like, then the integral has obviously no possible bound. Simply because I can take $\lambda_nf_n$ for a sufficiently large $\lambda_n$.

Comment: Yes, of course the bound should depend on the functions $f_n$. That's why I find the subscript $f_n$ confusing. To rephrase it, consider a fixed $n$ and a function $f$. I am looking for a bound of  $\left|\int_{\mathbb{S}_n(\sqrt{n})}[Z_1 f(Z) - \partial_1f(Z)] \, \mu_n(\mathrm{d}Z)\right|$ (bound that should depend on $n$ and on $f$ via Lipshitz constants for example.)

Comment: Ok; I see what you mean. Your argument with $n\to\infty$ was more of a motivation. I'm sorry

Comment: I changed the formulation :)